# Store x and y coords in Array list Java

Tags: java, coordinates

I want to store x and y coordinates from another class. I want to store it in an Array list. The coordinates should be taken from a click by mouse on a frame. I then want to draw lines between the clicks.

This is my process this far:

This is in jPanel.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class panel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public panel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    int x;
    int y;

    private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        x = evt.getX();
        y = evt.getY();
    }                                 

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);

        //XandY xy = new XandY(x,y);
        //System.out.println(xy);

        repaint();
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is in xandy class;

```java
public class XandY {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public XandY(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + "" + y;
    }
}
```

Please help me if you can.

edit:
I want a line between last clicked and next click and I do not know how to store that information. That is my main question.

Comment: You wrote what you want to achive but you not tell us where your problem is

Comment: I get you want to draw a line from the last clicked point to the new one or you want to draw straight lines like in a painting application? Anyway it would help you a lot if you called XandY simply Point (the rest of it looks pretty straight forward), in your panel class you could just save the last clicked point and draw a line on the event from the last clicked to the recently clicked (and update the last clicked)

Comment: You should [update your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75475799/store-x-and-y-coordinates-in-field-or-array-list-from-other-class) instead of reposting another one with similar issues

Comment: So what's stopping you? Make an `List<XandY> coords = new ArrayList();`. Then in `formMouseClicked()`, add an instance using the coords with `coords.add(new XandY(evt.getX(), evt.getY()));`. Now in `paintComponent()` walk the list and draw your lines...

Comment: BTW/FYI Java now (~2 Years) has a `record` data structure, making `XandY` easier... end even older, it also has `java.awt.Point` or `java.awt.geom.Point2D` for representing coordinates (and the `MouseEvent` even has a method to return a `Point`)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow common coding conventions and name your class starting with an uppercase letter.

You don't need to declare your own class `XandY`, Java provides `java.awt.Point` ready to use. Don't worry about the `double` result of `getX()` and `getY()`, Java will cast it to `int` for you if necessary.

You also do already paint something at the coordinates of the latest mouse click (in the method `paintComponent`), but to draw a line from the previous click, you need to store it's coordinates as well.

Add two member fields `private Point lastClick;` and `private Point currentClick;`. In the method `formMouseClicked` instead of assigning `x` and `y` (you don't need them!), assign a new Point to `currentClick`:

```
currentClick = new Point(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
```

In the method `paintComponent` you then have to check if both variables are actually set, and only run your code if they are:

```
private Point currentClick;
private Point lastClick;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  setBackground(Color.GRAY);
  g.setColor(Color.red);

  if (currentClick != null && currentclick != lastClick) {
    // to prevent actions when the method is called 
    //   without a mouse click since it was called last!
    g.fillOval(currentClick.getX(), currentClick.getY(), 50, 50);

    if (lastClick != null) {
      // now you have at least two clicks and can draw a line!
      g.drawLine(lastClick.getX(), lastClick.getY(), currentClick.getX(), currentClick.getY());
    }

    // and also store the current click as the last click!
    lastClick = currentClick;

    repaint();
  }
}
```